# C++ error: statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function

Tags: c++

I started programming C++ and I want to make a program for a game. I tried to build it and got the following error:

> error: statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function

It showed that for some of these lines:

```
cout << "Type in your statistics:"; endl; 
cout << "Kills:"; 
cin >> kills; endl;
cout << "Tode";
cin >> deaths; endl;
cout << "MaxDamage:";
cin >> maxDmg; endl;
cout << "TotalDamage:";
cin >> totalDmg; endl;
```

Comment: Which book taught you to write `; endl;` everywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove endl from cin statements

```
cout << "Type in your statistics:" << endl;
cout << "Kills:" << endl;
cin >> kills;
cout << "Tode" << endl;
cin >> deaths;
cout << "MaxDamage:" << endl;
cin >> maxDmg;
cout << "TotalDamage:" << endl;
cin >> totalDmg;
```

Comment: Of course you might want to output newlines, though, in which case you should just use `'\n`'.

Comment: How exactly do I add in line breaks?

Comment: @MarkTheSmasher: `std::endl` is a special function that you pass to a `std::ostream` with the stream insertion operator `<<`, and it writes a newline to the stream and then flushes it.  In other words, you'd use it like this: `std::cout << "hello world!" << std::endl;`. It does more than just writing a newline, so you should prefer it over manually writing newlines in most cases.

Comment: @Wug Actually no, you should prefer manually writing newlines in most cases. This isn't one of them though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, is that for efficiency purposes?

Comment: @user3670482: More or less. Flushing as a matter of course is usually superfluous. I don't do it unless I know I want it. It's a good habit to get into.

Comment: Perhaps for file IO, but not flushing output to stdio is asking for a print statement to mysteriously not work because it's sitting in a buffer somewhere unflushed while the program is blocking on something unrelated, or for a program crash to truncate output (because `cout` uses its own buffer, independent of the OS buffer allocated to the stdout file descriptor).  I'll point out that there's no practical difference for `cerr`, which flushes automatically every time it's written to.  I use `endl` everywhere because I think it looks better than inline escape sequences.